# Inductive proof of the number of ways to color $n$ identical balls with $j$ colors

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, solution-verification

> Let $F(n,j)$ be the number of ways to color $n$ identical balls with $j$ colors. Given the identity
>   $$F (n, j) = \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \binom ji F (n - j + i, j - i)$$
>   prove via induction that $F(n,j) = \binom{n+j-1}{j-1}$.

This was my attempt:

We proceed via strong induction. As a base case we have $n=j=1$ so that $F(n,j)=1=\binom{1+1-1}{1-1}$, so the identity holds. Inductive step for $n$: Suppose the identity holds for all $(n,j)$ pairs $(k,j)$ where $k \leq n$. We want to show that this means that the identity also holds for all pairs $(\leq n+1,j)$.  We have $$F (n+1, j) =
\sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \binom ji F ((n+1) - j + i, j - i)$$ and as $(n+1) - j + i \leq n$, we can use our identity then apply the inductive hypothesis to acquire

\begin{align*}
    F (n+1, j) &= \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \binom ji F ((n+1) - j + i, j - i) \\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \binom ji \binom{((n+1) - j + i) + (j-i) - 1}{(j-i)-1}\\
    &= \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} \binom ji \binom{n }{j-i-1}
\end{align*}

but this doesn't look very useful. Am I making a mistake somwehere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know [Vandermonde's identity](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vandermondes-identity/)?

$${m+n \choose k} = \sum_{r=0}^k {m \choose r}{n \choose k-r}$$

For the combinatorial proof, consider:
How many way can we pick $k$ objects out of $m+n$, conditional on having $r$ objects out of the first $m$?

---

Using that, your last step is equal to ${ n + j \choose j-1 } $, which is the form that you require.

Comment: Thanks! Also, do I need to perform induction on each variable, or is it sufficient to induce on $j$ for arbitrary $n$?

Comment: I have an issue with the way you phrase your induction step E.g. you don't have the case of $(n-j, j-1) $ assumed in the hypothesis step. Personally, I would have used strong induction on $n$ (proving for all $j$). IE Assuming works for $(x,y)$ pairs with $x < n$.